# Data from text file in ComboBox

Tags: c++, qt

I have ComboBox in Qt IDE and in this combobox are the names listed of employees. But there will come new names in it from time to time and some will be removed. So I thought that I could make a text file like this:

```
name 1
name 2
name 3
name 4
name 5 //and you keep going on
```

How do I get this list in a combobox?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get each item in a combobox, you can iterate through like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ui->comboBox->count(); ++i)
{
  qDebug() << ui->comboBox->itemText(i);
}
```